# Django query resolver for a specific field (graphql)

Tags: django, django-models, graphql, graphene-python, graphene-django

I want to make a query that only displays variant_view_configuration field. How can I solve the problem? If I write like that (return User.objects.get(pk=instance.id).variant_view_configuration), it gives me an error - but I need only variant_view_configuration

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    variant_view_configuration = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200), default=list, blank=True)

class UserQueries(object):
    user_variant_view_preference = graphene.Field(UserNode, id=graphene.ID(required=True))

    def resolve_user_variant_view_preference(self, info, id):
        instance = Node.get_node_from_global_id(info, id, only_type=UserNode)
        if not instance:
            raise ApplicationError.general.not_found(id)

        return User.objects.get(pk=instance.id).variant_view_configuration
```

The GraphQL query:

```
QUERY = """
    query Test($id: ID!) {
        userVariantViewPreference(id: $id) {
            variantViewConfiguration
        }
    }
"""


def test_user_variant_preference(graphql_request_maker):
    user = User.objects.create(
        username='username12',
        email='btestare@example.com',
        variant_view_configuration=["colors[0].sizes[0].size", "details.country_of_origin"]
    )

    data, err = graphql_request_maker.make(
        QUERY,
        {
            "id": to_global_id('UserNode', user.id)
        }
    )
```

So, as I say, I want a query that return only and only variant_view_configuration for a specific User id.

I am new to django and graphql, please explain how I do this.
Thank you!

Comment: If the problem is that you don't wanna show another fields of your user models you can simple use `return User.objects.filter(pk=instance.id).only('variant_view_configuration')`

Comment: The problem is not the queryset, is your `user_variant_view_preference = graphene.Field` you got to use `user_variant_view_preference = graphene.List` because you are returning a list of objects

Comment: What does the error message say?

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest that you filter through the instance.id and not get the instance id. So a good practice would be this:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    variant_view_configuration = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200), default=list, blank=True)

class UserQueries(object):
    user_variant_view_preference = graphene.Field(UserNode, id=graphene.ID(required=True))

    def resolve_user_variant_view_preference(self, info, id):
        instance = Node.get_node_from_global_id(info, id, only_type=UserNode)
        if not instance:
            raise ApplicationError.general.not_found(id)

        return User.objects.filter(pk=instance.id).only('variant_view_configuration')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the resolver type from `UserNode` to `graphene.List(graphene.String)`:

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    variant_view_configuration = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200), default=list, blank=True)

class UserQueries(object):
    user_variant_view_preference = graphene.List(graphene.String, id=graphene.ID(required=True))

    def resolve_user_variant_view_preference(self, info, id):
        instance = Node.get_node_from_global_id(info, id, only_type=UserNode)
        if not instance:
            raise ApplicationError.general.not_found(id)

        return User.objects.get(pk=instance.id).variant_view_configuration
```